# Intersection of all 1/n neighborhoods of closed set

Tags: metric-spaces

I need to prove that the intersection of all 1/n neighborhoods of a closed set gives me the set itself.  However, i have no idea how to even start this proof (to me it seems like it's false) Does anyone have any tips/hints on how to start it?

Comment: If a point does not belong to the set, is there a number $n$ such that the point does not belong to $1/n$ neighborhood of the set too?

Comment: What do you men by the 1/n neighborhood of the set?  Aren't neighborhoods defined only for points?

Comment: @Alex: $B_\epsilon(S) = \bigcup_{x\in S} B_\epsilon(x) = \{ y \mid \exists x \in S : |x-y| < \epsilon \}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose x is not in the set, call it E.  E is closed so x is *not* a limit point.  So there is an $\epsilon$ such that B($\epsilon$, x) has no point of E.  We can find an m such that 0 < $\frac{1}{m}$< $\epsilon$. So B($\frac{1}{m}$, x) has no point of E.  So for all y  in E, d(x, y) > $\frac{1}{m}$.  So x is *not* in the $\frac{1}{m}$ set of E.  So x is not in the intersection of $\frac{1}{n}$ neighborhoods.  So the only x that *are* in the intersection must also be in E.

So the intersection is a subset of E.

And clearly E is a subset of any $\frac{1}{n}$ neighborhood so E is a subset of the intersections.  So E = the intersection.